# Htaccess on XAMPP local server for testing

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I finally got the XAMPP local Wordpress system working so now I can test things out.

If I want to mimic htaccess files to test redirect code and so forth - especially htaccess in the root - here would I put the htaccess file?

I'm thinking is the XAMPP folder considered the "root"? I've taken a snapshot of my directories to give you an idea.  The checkmarks are there just to show you the general layout of the directories.

One other thing - suppose I wanted to create a sub-directory (like localhost/sub/index.php) to test in XAMPP.  Is this possible?  I noticed when I'm in local host there is no multi-site capability.  Thoughts?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.htaccess` file should be in the root of your `WordPress` installation and you may use sub-directories to create more local sites. For example:

```
localhost/wordpress = xampp/htdocs/wordpress/index.php
localhost/anothersite = xampp/htdocs/anothersite/index.php
// More...
```

For the `WordPress` installation, put the `.htaccess` in the `wordpress` directory in example (At the same level where the `index.php` file is stored).